# Dead Money DLC Perks

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

What are the new perks in the Dead Money DLC for Fallout: New Vegas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_perks):

- [And Stay Back](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/And_Stay_Back): Shotguns have a chance of knocking an enemy back
- [In Shining Armor](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/In_Shining_Armor): +5 Damage threshold against energy weapons when wearing metal armor, +2 when wearing when wearing reflective eyewear.
- [Junk Rounds](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Junk_Rounds): You can craft ammo from scrap metal and tin cans.
- [Light Touch](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Light_Touch): While wearing light armor, you get a +5% critical chance, and your enemies get a -25% critical chance against you.
- [Old World Gourmet](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Old_World_Gourmet): +25% addiction resistance. +50% health bonus from snack foods. Scotch, vodka and wine now give you health in addition to their normal effects.
- [Heavyweight](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Heavyweight): Weapons with a weight of more than 10 is cut in half. This does not affect weapons modded to under 10 weight.